# Render crash on tessallating cube

Tags: rendering

Every time I render this liquid in a bowl simulation it'll get as far as to tessellating cube.001 3/3.  I've tried lowering the fluid quality and remove its subdivision surface.  I've even recreated the whole fluid part of it.  There is no cube.001 in the hierarchy but when i was modeling i had that but later removed it.  I doubt it but would blender still keep it?  If i use the rendered view it works fine but when I render it just freezes and I have to restart my computer.  My computer is also high end being a Alien ware Aurora R5.  If you can help thank you.

[Blend File](https://mega.nz/#!9R1mRKqJ!rBKcBlawKan2WbVDpW9uWLTCmZiAHSoOG47qhzUBT1k)

Comment: Could you please clarify your workflow and how you are subdividing and rendering your scene? perhaps post some screenshots of your simulation and modifier and physics settings.

Comment: please **only** host blend files on [blend exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).